# "foreach" em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, foreach

A título de exemplo, em PHP temos a função [**foreach()**](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que nos permite executar determinado código por cada elemento encontrado numa matriz:

```php
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
  echo "acção para o valor " . $value;
}

// Saída:
// acção para o valor 1
// ...
?>
```

Recorrendo à mesma função, podemos percorrer a matriz e obter a chave e o respectivo valor respeitante a cada elemento encontrado:

```php
<?php
$arr = array(
  "primeiro" => "John",
  "ultimo"   => "Doe"
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' nome: ' . $value . "<br>";
}

// Saída:
// primeiro nome: John
// ultimo nome: Doe
?>
```

## Pergunta

Como posso realizar este tipo de operações com uma matriz em JavaScript ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Em primeiro lugar, **as matrizes do PHP são diferentes das do JavaScript**

Um exemplo de matriz tradicional seria:

```
var matriz = [1,2,3,4];
```

Já o que em PHP é uma matriz associativa, em JavaScript é um objeto:

```
var obj = {
    primeiro: 'John',
    ultimo: 'Doe'
};
```

Como disse o @utluiz, em JavaScript existe o [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), que serve para iterar sobre as chaves de um objeto. Como arrays também são objetos, também é possível iterar sobre elas, mas isso não é recomendável devido a algumas características do `for..in`:

1. O `for..in` itera sobre todas as chaves enumeráveis do objeto.
2. O `for..in` também itera sobre todas as chaves de propriedades (enumeráveis) herdadas do protótipo do objeto.
3. A especificação do JavaScript não exige uma ordem específica para as chaves percorridas pelo `for..in`. Diferentes browsers podem usar ordens diferentes e é possível que as chaves do vetor não sejam acessadas em ordem crescente.

Essas características podem trazer problemas, especialmente se você utiliza bibliotecas ou *polyfills* que modificam `Array.prototype`.

### Portanto, não use `for..in` para iterar sobre uma matriz; use um `for` comum

```
var matriz = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i=0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, matriz[i]); // i é o índice, matriz[i] é o valor
}
```

Se quiser algo um pouco mais próximo da versão PHP:

```
var matriz = [1,2,3,4];
for(var chave=0, valor; valor=matriz[chave], chave<matriz.length; chave++) {
    console.log(chave, valor); // chave é o índice, valor é o valor
}
```

Existem ainda outras alternativas, em browsers com suporte ao ECMAScript 5 (o que não inclui o IE8). Por exemplo, o [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) mencionado pelo Luiz Vieira:

```
var matriz = [1,2,3,4];
matriz.forEach(function(valor, chave){
    console.log(chave, valor);
});
```

Se o objetivo da iteração for criar uma nova matriz com transformações dos valores orignais, você pode usar o [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var matriz = [1,2,3,4];
// Nova matriz onde cada valor é o dobro
var dobros = matriz.map(function(valor){
    return valor * 2;
});
console.log(dobros); // [2,4,6,8];
```

Se o objetivo for criar uma nova matriz com somente alguns dos valores orignais, você pode usar o [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var matriz = [1,2,3,4];
// Nova matriz só com valores pares
var pares = matriz.filter(function(valor){
    return valor % 2 == 0;
});
console.log(pares); // [2,4];
```

Nessa mesma linha, vale dar uma olhada nos métodos [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) e [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

### Para iterar sobre objetos, aí sim use o `for..in`

```
var obj = {
    primeiro: 'John',
    ultimo: 'Doe'
};
for(var tipoNome in obj) {
    console.log(tipoNome, obj[tipoNome]);
}
```

Mas atenção: esse tipo de iteração pode incluir propriedades herdadas. Por exemplo:

```
function Cachorro(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
Cachorro.prototype.latir = function() {
    console.log('au au!');    
};
var godofredo = new Cachorro('Godofredo');
for(var prop in godofredo) {
    console.log(prop); // loga 'latir' e 'nome'
}
```

Para evitar o problema, você pode fazer uma checagem com [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
for(var prop in godofredo) {
    if(godofredo.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(prop); // loga somente 'nome'
    }
}
```

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta! Muito didática e esclarecedora. (y)

Answer (score 7):

## Alternativa semelhante: `for..in`

Em Javascript existe uma versão do `for` que possui algumas semelhanças com o `foreach` do PHP. É o tipo de construção mais próxima, porém ele existe para iterar sobre propriedades de objetos e não necessariamente índices de vetores. Além disso, não é possível obter a chave e o valor automaticamente.

A sintaxe é:

```js
for (<índice> in <vetor/objeto>)
```

Exemplo:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (index in array) {
    var value = array[index];
    console.log("array[" + index + "] = " + value);
}
```

Exemplo funcional no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZbaG/).

## Iterando sobre propriedades de objetos

Como mencionei, este tipo de *loop* não é direcionado exatamente para *arrays*, sendo útil principalmente para iterar sobre as propriedades de um objeto qualquer:

Exemplo:

```js
var object = { nome: 'Luiz', idade: 29};
for (property in object) {
    var value = object[property];
    console.log("object[" + property + "] = " + value);
}
```

Exemplo funcional no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a68q3/1/).

Uma aplicação comum é simular um mapa ou dicionário de dados. Outro exemplo é um vetor esparso (que não contém todos os índices sequencialmente de `0` a `n`.

## Atenção para possíveis problemas

Como mencionado em outras respostas e em comentários, o loop `for...in` pode resultar em efeitos colaterais indesejados.

Por exemplo, se uma biblioteca definir uma ou mais funções no `prototype` do objeto. Estas funções serão incluídas no laço `for..in` e seria necessário usar a função `hasOwnProperty` para ignorar essas funções "herdadas".

Além disso, não garantido que índices numéricos serão percorridos em alguma ordem.

## Dica: evite mexer no `prototype`

Do meu ponto de vista, mexer no `prototype` de objetos comuns deveria ser evitado a todo custo, assim como bibliotecas que fazem tal uso.

Por exemplo, imagine que vamos usar um objeto como um mapa, atribuindo e recuperando dinamicamente atributos do mesmo. Ao percorrer as chaves desse mapa, terei que lembrar de *sempre* usar a função `hasOwnProperty`.

A questão é: deveríamos mesmo ter que se preocupar se que alguém injetou algum elemento "estranho" em nossos objetos? Eu acredito que não.

## Na prática...

Embora o `for..in` seja sempre acusado de causar problemas, em minha experiência nunca tive dificuldades em usá-lo tanto em *arrays* quanto em *objetos* normais, sem o `hasOwnProperty`. Provavelmente isso se deve ao fato de nunca permitir código "estranho" injetando funções "mágicas" sem meu conhecimento.

Além disso, embora a ordem dos elementos não seja garantida pela especificação, também nunca presenciei em nenhum navegador índices sendo percorridos fora de ordem, pelo menos em *arrays* de verdade.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var array = new Array();

array.push("A");
array.push("B");
array.push("C");

delete array[1]
array[1] = 2;

for (i in array) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

Mesmo deletando um índice do meio do *array* e depois redefinindo-o, o resultado será `0`, `1` e `2`, nesta ordem. Veja o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Bz5D/). Se alguém descobrir algum navegador que se comporte diferente, por favor, me avise.

Por outro lado, se **não usar um *array* de verdade** o resultado é diferente. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var array = { }

array[0] = "A";
array[2] = "B";
array[1] = "C";

for (i in array) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

Veja o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3Lz/1/).

Surpreendentemente, o resultado no Chrome é `0`, `1` e `2`. No entanto, no Firefox e IE é `0`, `2` e `1`. Enfim, a não ser que você use um objeto como um vetor esparso, isto é, adicionando elementos maiores antes dos menores, não haveria problemas em usar o `for..in`.

Enfim, o mesmo cuidado para uso do `for..in` em *arrays* serve para qualquer objeto, então recomendações como "não use isso" simplesmente não fazem sentido. Mesmo que o `prototype` seja alterado, desde que eu use sempre o `hasOwnProperty()` e não me importe com a ordem dos elementos, não há problemas em usar este tipo de *loop*.

## Considerações finais

De maneira geral, realmente é melhor evitar o `for..in` e optar pelo o `for` tradicional. Motivos:

- Você pode vir a precisar de uma biblioteca que altere o `prototype`. É comum ouvir relatos de pessoas que acrescentam uma certa biblioteca Javascript e ela "quebra" sua implementação.
- Evita ainda que outros desenvolvedores usem indevidamente o `prototype` e quebrem o código geral do sistema.
- Permite que objetos simulem um *array*, definindo a propriedade `length` e atributos numéricos. Isto é muito útil para rotinas genéricas que recebem vetores. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

  ```js
  var array = {
      0: "Primeiro",
      1: "Segundo",
      2: "Terceiro",
      length: 3
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      console.log('array[' + i + '] = ' + array[i]);
  }
  ```

Veja o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Le6p/).

Comment: Não use for-in para iterar vetores. Não há garantia de que os indices serão acessados em ordem crescente (que é o que a maioria dos programadores espera)

Comment: @missingno Acho muito superficial esse tipo de afirmação. Eu gosto de dar opções para as pessoas e não simplesmente restringir o uso de um recurso só porque ***pode*** causar algum efeito colateral. Reformulei a resposta com uma análise mais profunda sobre a questão. Estou meio sem tempo, mas fique à vontade se tiver alguma observação ou crítica que cedo ou tarde eu passo para dar mais uma revisada. Abraço.

Answer (score 7):

Via jQuery, por uma abordagem simples, você pode utilizar o método jQuery.each() que permite iterar sobre objetos/arrays separando-os por índice/valor

Exemplo:

```
$.each([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], function( index, value ) {
    alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Referência: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 4):

Em adição à todas as respostas existentes, existe o [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) do ECMAScript 6 (ou seja, novo :/) que percorre valores de objetos incluindo uma propriedade especial `Symbol.iterator` (essa propriedade é um símbolo... e lembrando que símbolos não são enumeráveis!). Instâncias de `Array`, `Map`, `Set`, `String` e `TypedArray`, e o objeto `arguments` gerado por funções já são percorríveis, desde que tenham a propriedade especial `Symbol.iterator`.

Observação: só há uma desvantagem em usar o *for... of*. Ele não te deixa saber qual a índice do valor atual.

P.S.: as classes/interfaces citadas acima armazenam essa propriedade `Symbol.iterator` na própria prototype. Essa propriedade deve retornar uma função (se você ver no console, `[][Symbol.iterator]`, irá se deparar com uma função nomeada `'values'`), e essa mesma função deveria retornar um objeto. `[][Symbol.iterator]()` retorna uma instância nativa de `ArrayIterator`.

Exemplo de como percorrer uma `Array` com pares de chave e valor:

```js
const pairs = [
    [ 'yum', 'yam' ],
    [ 'haha', true ]
];

for (let [k, v] of pairs) {
    console.log(k, v);
}
```

Exemplo percorrendo uma `Array` de forma comum:

```js
for (let v of [ 1, 2, 3 ]) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse exemplo (extraído [dessa fonte original no SO(en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript)) utiliza a função `forEach` existente em objetos do tipo `array` a partir do ECMAScript5:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

`var i = -1; while(vetor[++i]){}`

Testei no Chrome e funciona bem !

Comment: Se `vetor[++i]`tiver dentro um valor Booleano falso isso não vai funcionar...