# Como fazer um foreach no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array-multidimensional

Minha aplicação retorna um array de array, em que `campanhas[]` é um array de `campanha[]` que também é um array.

Como posso fazer um `foreach` para pegar cada campanha de dentro do array `campanhas`?

Segue abaixo o retorno array de um array:

```
this.campanhas{campanha1{},campanha2{} ,campanha3{}}
```

Comment: Essa pergunta já possui respostas em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2506/foreach-em-javascript

Comment: `foreach` está mais para [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) do que `for...in`, como costumam associar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `loop` tipo `for(valor in array)` que irá pegar o valor que você deseja.

Exemplo para pegar o `valor1` de cada sub-array em `campanhas`:

```js
var campanhas = {
   campanha1: {
      valor1: "a",
      valor2: "b"
   },
   campanha2: {
      valor1: "c",
      valor2: "d"
   },
   campanha3: {
      valor1: "e",
      valor2: "f"
   }
};

for(valor in campanhas){
   console.log(campanhas[valor].valor1);
}
```

Comment: dvd , Eu tinha feito exatamente assim e por algum motivo , não conseguia passar o valor

Comment: Depois eu percebi que meu problema não era com o for em si , mas com o retorno do array campanhas, essa resolução funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

Posso te sugerir utilizar o forEach nativo do ECMAScript, porém caso queria dar suporte à browsers antigos, basta incluir um simples polyfill na sua aplicação:

```
if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

E utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
    console.log("a[" + index + "] = " + element);
}
[2, 5, 9].forEach(logArrayElements);
// logs:
// a[0] = 2
// a[1] = 5
// a[2] = 9
```

mais informações na [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)