# diferenças entre for...in em JS e em Python

Tags: javascript, python, loop

no codigo a seguir em Python...

```
string = "abcd"
for i in string:
    print(i)
---------------
output:
a
b
c
d
```

e em JavaScript

```
string = "abcd"
for(i in string)
    console.log(i)
---------------
output:
0
1
2
3
```

O que faz os retornos serem diferentes? É possível fazer o tipo de retorno do Python em JS e vice-versa?

Comment: Resposta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2515/64969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python tem um for que desde o começo da linguagem, na década de 90 foi uma construção para percorrer uma sequência. Um bloco que em outras linguagens de programação, ou em termos genéricos, chamamos de `for each` ou  `for in`. Em particular ele é bem diferente de um `while`, e sempre vai percorrer uma sequência - seja a sequência de caracteres de uma string, uma sequência de números numa lista ou num array, e assim por diante.

A linguagem é notadamente consistente com isso, dentro de sua filosofia de prover o máximo de valor para fazer certo as pequenas coisas de forma que o desenvolvedor possa se preocupar com o seu algoritmo, e não ficar brigando com a linguagem. Nos casos, que são minoria ,(embora não raros) em que o `for` precisa ou de uma sequência numérica ou do índice dos elementos de uma sequência, pode-se usar as funcionalidades `range` e `enumerate` da linguagem.

Para criar o retorno numérico em Python, em geral usamos o método enumerate - já que mesmo com o índice em mãos, vamos em geral precisar do conteúdo da sequência naquele índice:

```
for i, letra in enumerate("abcd"):
    print (i, letra)

---
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'd')
```

Se você fizer questão de ter só os números, é só usar `range` até o comprimento da sequência:

```
for i in range(len("abcd")):
    print(i)
```

(embora em geral encontrar `for i in range(len(...)):` seja mais um indicativo de que o desenvolvedor está acostumado com outra linguagem e aprendendo Python do que sinal de um bom código - pelo simples motivo de que você quase sempre vai querer o conteúdo da sequência, e apenas na minoria das vezes o índice - mas quase nunca só os índices - basta tentar pensar em um exemplo de problema real que precise só dos índices para verificar isso)

Já Javascript, assim como outras linguagens derivadas da linguagem C (Java, PHP, C#, C++, Objective C, Perl) tem na verdade um `for` que é quase o mesmo que um `while`, com a única diferença que a expressão para inicialização e a condição de final ficam agrupados. (compare `for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {...}` com `i = 0; while (i < 10) {...; i++}` .

Em algum ponto na história do Javascript, criaram o `for in` (não consegui achar quando - ele já estava presente na primeira especificação EcmaScript de 1997. Antes disso, Javascript era o que cada browser colocava como Javascript) - mas em vez de percorrer os elementos de uma sequência, optaram por devolver uma sequência numérica para com um número para cada chave existente no objeto - uma escolha feita talvez por que não tinha como manter a consistência, já  que Javascript não tem propriamente sequências internamente como as listas de Python - tanto objetos, como sequências como mappings são coisas mais ou menos intercambiáveis em Javascript, meio "molengas":

```
> ￼a = [0,1,2]
< [0, 1, 2]
> a["chave"] = "valor";
< "valor"
> a
< [0, 1, 2, chave: "valor"]
```

Para manter a consistência, o `for in` do Javascritp também retornas os índices quando o elemento é uma string. O jeito óbvio de percorrer os valores associados a cada índice é fazer uma atribuição nas primeiras linhas do `for`:

```
for (i in palavra="abcd") {var letra=palavra[i]; console.log(letra);}
```

Só que aí entra em jogo uma outra idiossincrasia do Javascript - de novo por conta do histórico da linguagem, ela não tem uma separação entre "instâncias" e "classes" como em linguagens orientadas a objeto tradicionais, trabalhando com a noção de protótipos, em que "tudo é um objeto com poderes iguais, e qualquer objeto pode ser o protótipo de outro funcionando como uma 'classe' ". (Na prática, você pode rodar a internet inteira e não achar nenhum texto que consiga mostrar qualquer vantagem dessa "orientação a objetos por protótipos", em vez do uso bem definido de classes e instâncias (o máximo que mesmo os maiores fãs da ideia conseguem chegar é que  "não é tão ruim assim"). Ok, bom, o problema disso é que num objeto javascript, não há automaticamente uma distinção entre atributos que seriam do "protótipo" de um objeto e os atributos do próprio objeto - como acontecem em Python que tem classes e instâncias distintos.  Então, se você executar a linha acima para tentar imprimir letra a letra, vai ter:

```
for (i in palavra="abcd") {var letra=palavra[i]; console.log(letra);}

>  a
>  b
>  c
>  d
>  ƒ (){var e=this.toString();if(!arguments.length)return e;var t=typeof arguments[0],n="string"==t||"number"==t?Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments):arguments[0];for(var i in n)e=e.replace(new RegExp("\…
>  ƒ (e,t){var n=this.toString();return e&&n.length>e&&(n=n.substr(0,e)+t),n}
>  ƒ (e){var t=this.lastIndexOf(e);return 0>t?[this]:[this.substr(0,t),this.substr(t)]}
>  ƒ (e){return this.indexOf(e)>-1}
```

Ou seja: depois do índice da última letra aparecem os atributos do protótipo da string.

Há como contornar isso chamando-se o método `.isOwnProperty` de cada chave do `for in`:

```
for (i in palavra="abcd") {var letra=palavra[i]; if (!palavra.hasOwnProperty(i)) {continue;}  console.log(letra);}
>  a
>  b
>  c
>  d
```

## Resposta:

Na pratica, a forma como as coisas funcionam no Python são muito práticas, o que fez com que desenvolvimentos posteriores no javascript ou em bibliotecas tentassem melhorar a funcionalidade de um `for each`. Então, em algum ponto foi introduzido o `for (elemento of object)` (`for of`), que consegue extrair os elementos de uma sequência ou objeto, e tratar strings como sequências:

```
for (letra of "abcd") {console.log(letra)}
> 1 a
> 1 b
> 1 c
> 1 d
```

## Continuando

... mas o `for of` não funciona para objetos gerais - apenas arrays e strings (e talvez algum outro tipo de objeto):

```
for (element of {"a": "A", "b": "B"}) console.log(element);
> Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not iterable at <anonymous>:1:17
```

Na busca histórica de uma solução, antes do `for of`
existem outras abordagens: para objetos do tipo `Array`, há um método `forEach`  que percorre os seus elementos. Mas como isso não é parte da sintaxe da linguagem, e  sim, um método como outro qualquer, em vez de abrir um bloco com os comandos a serem executados, você passa uma função que será chamada para cada elemento da sequência. Como Javascript permite funções arbitrárias inline, isso é *quase* que só uma questão de colocar as marcações sintáticas `(function (parametro)  {...} )` em vez de só um bloco `{ ...}` - mas tem efeitos colaterais, como o nome `this` é resignificado, há um outro escopo de variáveis, e etc...:

```
a.forEach(function (letra){ console.log(letra);})

>  a
>  b
>  c
>  d
```

Claro, que há ainda o inconveniente disso funcionar para Arrays, mas não funcionar para strings, enquanto que em Python as duas coisas (pensando em listas, no lugar de arrays), tem a mesma interface de "sequências".

Então, por "demanda popular", um dos pacotes terceirizados mais populares de Javascript, o jQuery, implementou a função "each" que faz o mesmo que o "forEach" do Array para qualquer objeto.  Como a chance é grande que sua página já inclua o jQuery em alguma forma, você pode usar esse método para iterar sobre as chaves de objetos genéricos, como acontece com os dicionários em Python:

```
$.each({"a": "A", "b": "B"}, function (letra) {console.log(letra)} )
> a
> b
```

O jQuery, mantendo a tradição do Javascript, não pode fazer isso ser consistente para todas as finalidades óbvias, então apesar de seu `.each` funcionar para quase qualquer objeto, não funciona para strings. Para strings você deve mesmo usar a resposta acima, ou achar ainda outro módulo que faça isso.

Comment: a resposta não poderia ser melhor, esclareceu minhas duvidas! muito obrigado!